# sed: add text at some byte offset after matching pattern

Tags: unix, sed

I've got a file like this:

`113728482180.18408400639521053213728482180.18534013377161235313728482180.18527849814511801413728482180.12680711716571988513728482180.40802725786530114613728482180.039221670254883746713728482180.42748179436369843813728482180.45107192556631565913728482180.43916947404834661013728482180.12677684033447337`

How do I add text (in this case a `\n`) 11 characters before the position that matches `0.`?

I want to end up with something like:

```
113728482180.18408400639521053
213728482180.18534013377161235
313728482180.18527849814511801
413728482180.12680711716571988
513728482180.40802725786530114
613728482180.039221670254883746
713728482180.42748179436369843
813728482180.45107192556631565
913728482180.43916947404834661
013728482180.12677684033447337
```

I possible, I would also like to solve the following. The first digit of each line is a counter (1, 2, 3, ..., 10, ..., 10000, ...). The last digit from the 9th line (which is 1) should also be included in the 10th line so as to this line begin with 10, rather than 0. This would also be necessary for 1000s, 10000s and 100000s.

Is it possible? Something like, for the lines 1-9, the offset would be 11, for the lines 10-99, the offset would be 12, for the lines 100-999, the offset would be 13, and so on.

For the example above, the last two lines would become:

```
913728482180.4391694740483466
1013728482180.12677684033447337
```

The counter is sequential. For larger numbers, in the order of hundreds and thousands, just adding the newline 11 characters before the match would end up like this in the case of 10000s:

```
213728482180.43916947404831000
313728482180.12677684033441000
```

But the aim is to get:

```
1000213728482180.4391694740483
1000313728482180.1267768403344
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this: (gnu sed)

```
 sed -r 's/([^.]{12}\.)/\n\1/2g' file
```

example:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/([^.]{12}\.)/\n\1/2g' a
113728482180.18408400639521053
213728482180.18534013377161235
313728482180.18527849814511801
413728482180.12680711716571988
513728482180.40802725786530114
613728482180.039221670254883746
713728482180.42748179436369843
813728482180.45107192556631565
913728482180.43916947404834661
013728482180.12677684033447337
```

Comment: That works, thanks! What about the second part of the question? Is it possible?

Comment: I've edited that part of the question. I think it is more clearer now.

Comment: could you pls provide an expected output as example?

Comment: I think I roughly get what you want, but not sure.  I think it could be done by awk or perl. sed would be very hard to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, perl: `perl -ne 'BEGIN { $c=1 } while ($_) { $c1 = $c + 1; m/^($c((\d{11}\.)\d+))($c1\3.*|$)/; print "$c: $2\n"; $c++; $_ = $4; }' file`

Answer (score 0):

How about using a for loop of bash with sed?

```
str="..."
for II in `seq 2 10`; do
  str=`echo $str | sed -e 's#\('$II'13728482180\.\)# \1#'`
done
echo $str | tr ' ' '\n'
```

You may replace the `seq 2 10` by your own number N, `seq 2 N`, if known in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored in a file named `data`, Bash + sed:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read -r num; do
    printf -v pre 's/^[0-9]*(%s[0-9]{11}\.)/\\1/' "${i:=1}"
    printf -v suf 's/(\.[0-9]+)%s[0-9]{11}$/\\1/' "$((++i))"
    sed -r -e"$pre" -e"$suf" <<<"$num"
done < <(sed -r 's/([1-9]*)\.([0-9]*)/\1.\2\n\2/g' data | head -n -1)
```

gives:

```
113728482180.18408400639521053
213728482180.18534013377161235
313728482180.18527849814511801
413728482180.12680711716571988
513728482180.40802725786530114
613728482180.039221670254883746
713728482180.42748179436369843
813728482180.45107192556631565
913728482180.4391694740483466
1013728482180.12677684033447337
```

This is a compiled sed statement looping over the output of another sed statement. The outer sed statement duplicates each decimal with a newline, creating a list like:

```
A.B
B.C
C.D
```

This is read line-by-line to the `$num` variable. Each iteration creates two new regexes with literal numbers to delineate the sequence (which is presumably of unknown size but possibly going over 1000).

This may not be the fastest method, but it will get the job done without OOMing. On my system it took 51.144s to process 20,000 records.